# Umbraco duplicated master directive

Tags: master-pages, umbraco

Each time we modify an umbraco masterpage outside of the umbraco admin editor we get the whole masterpage wrapped with this directive:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

Does anyone know if there's a config flag to avoid this?

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen svn merges do this (sometimes repeatedly) where one person has the original empty 'wrapper' master directive - someone else changes it in Visual Studio and then SVN merges all the new changes inside the original wrapper.  Especially seems to happen when you change the master inheritance.

So I'm not sure its an Umbraco issue that's solvable with a config key.

**EDIT**

I'm not certain but usually this behaviour stops when the site edits 'settle down' - I think it is connected to the way the csproj files stores the list of files in the project - once everyone 'include in project' all the masterpages, the problem goes away. But I'm not sure, as its difficult to reproduce once it stops.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to avoid this behaviour? it seems to happen in any of the three development machines and as well as on the staging server. No one has an empty "wrapper", we all have the latest version, but whenever there's a change/commit and update from svn we all get the same bug.

Comment: @ahmed I'm not certain but usually this behaviour stops when the site edits 'settle down' - I think it is connected to the way the csproj files stores the list of files in the project - once everyone 'include in project' all the masterpages, the problem goes away.  But I'm not sure, as its difficult to reproduce once it stops.